# Get AllocationID in aws cli for powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cli

How to filter out AllocationId for Elastic IP address in AWS cli 2.0 in Powershell.

```
aws ec2 describe-addresses --query 'Addresses[?AssociationId!=`null`].{AllocId:AllocationId} | [0]' --output text --region ap-southeast-2 --filters "Name=tag:xxx,Values=xxx"
```

tried this, returns `Null`. Need help especially with `TAG` filter.

I am trying to automate the process of EIP allocation to my newly generated Instance from autoscaling group.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as it working for me, I just reorder the command query after filter.

```
aws ec2 describe-addresses --region ap-southeast-2 --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=xxx"  --query 'Addresses[?AssociationId!=`null`] | [0]'  --output table
```

Comment: I tried this query, We have used this in past in other User data scripts and they work fine. But it does not work in Cli 2.0 in powershell. I do not know why.

Comment: I am also using aws-cli 2.0